# How can head and body tags appear in both index.php and header.php

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm taking my first steps in developing WordPress themes, currently going through the twenty ten theme, and I was wondering how come both index.php and header.php contain the `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: Maybe wrong index.php (there are several) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.php there's a function get_header(), which calls header.php (which has the body and head tags).

I recommend downloading the theme again, because I'm sure there can't be such an error in that theme.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

@nikolay you are absolutely correct

In the twenty ten theme, im sure  and  tags is not present in both index and header pages.
Mostly  tag will be present in header file.